# When talking to the townspeople, do I have to finish the conversation to earn full friendship points?

Tags: stardew-valley

In Stardew Valley, one of the main objectives is to make friends with as many of the villagers as possible. One way to do this is by talking to them every day. As per [the wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Friendship), speaking with other villagers earns you 20 friendship points per person per day.

Usually, once you've talked to a villager for the day, you will be unable to talk to them again for the rest of the day (the speech bubble icon will not appear when mousing over them). However, some villagers will occasionally have multi-part dialogs, where you can talk to them a few times in a row as they elaborate on things they just said (for example, Penny explaining how it's difficult to keep her house clean without help from her drunken mother, a conversation which consists of 4 distinct dialogs, each of which you have to re-click on Penny for). My question is, do you get the full 20 points immediately after the first dialog, or do you have to finish the full conversation to get the points?

Comment: Wow clearly someone does not deserve full friendship points :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like simply talking to them will give all 20 Friendship points, even if you don't finish the conversation.

See [this thread](http://community.playstarbound.com/threads/questions-on-talking-to-villagers.111818/):

> 1. If a villager has a conversation that lasts multiple clicks, do you need to go through the whole thing, or just the first one?
>
> Just the first thing. As long as you interact with them to get the dialogue box up, you get the points.

In [this wiki chat log](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Talk:Friendship), it looks like someone had been wondering the same thing as you:

> So it's apparently either +10 or +20. Any info on why? Any speculations? Any chance it could have something to do with whether or not you "finish" their dialogue for the day (for example, talking to them once when they have multiple dialogues gives +10, but talking to them and finishing the dialogues gives +20)?

It appears that this has been figured out as the [wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Friendship) now explains the reasoning behind differing Friendship point gains:

> talking to villagers (+10 if the villager is in the middle of a special animation, like exercising or using a camera, otherwise +20; can only score once per day);

Thus, as long as you converse with a villager at least once a day and they're *not in the middle of something special*, you'll get +20 Friendship points, even if the conversation could have kept going.

Comment: So, in other words... "Hi villager!" "Hello Farmer, let me tell you about my day." "No thanks not interested, bye" "What a nice person. I'm glad to be his friend."

Comment: @MageXy sounds like [Ron Swanson](https://youtu.be/5XU5iqrhwW0)

Comment: @MageXy If you think that's bad, I've basically been forcefeeding them hundreds of Oranges and Peaches to get them to like me.

Comment: @SGR There's a bug in the game right now where certain wallpapers having conflicting item IDs with other items. In particular, there's a light green one that has the same item ID as the prismatic shard, which is a universally loved item. I hate to admit it, but I bought the catalog from Pierre's shop so I could get infinite wallpapers for free, and I've been giving those to everyone in Pelican Town. I guess everyone just really likes decorating!